# How to test more than just java files using the Checkstyle Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

We use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to enforce basic code quality rules in our multi-project [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) build. Some of these rules apply across all file types, not just Java files, but we can't figure out how to configure the [Checkstyle Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) to look at anything other than `$projectDir/src/$sourceSet/java`.

One of the most basic rules we'd like to enforce is that tab characters never be used. The relevant bits of `checkstyle.xml`:

```xml
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

and the snippet of `build.gradle` that configures the plugin:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
  configFile = new File(rootDir, 'checkstyle.xml')
}
```

In addition to `java/**/*` we'd also like to check all files in `conf/**/*` and `www/**/*` (assuming include specs are relative to the source set root). However, if I try adding those include rules:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
  configFile = new File(rootDir, 'checkstyle.xml')
  include 'conf/**/*'
  include 'www/**/*'
}
```

we get the following error:

```
> Could not find method include() for arguments [conf/**/*] on org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension_Decorated@467763f.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring the appropriate `Checkstyle` task directly. For example:

```
tasks.checkstyle { // `checkstyle` alone refers to the extension, not the task
    source "src/main/conf"
    source "src/main/www"
}
```

For more information, see `Checkstyle` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Thanx. For some reason I misread the docs for source and thought it was used to declare additional sourceSets.

Comment: The `checkstyle` *extension* has a `sourceSets` property.